# Binding store model collection in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to **bind** the store in Ember to templates, so that when a new object is being **pushed** to the store the template will be updated?
Eg:
~ route.js

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    this.store.findAll('post')
)
```

~ template.hbs

```
{{#each post in controller}}
    {{title} <br />
{{/each}}
```

~ controller.js

```
App.SomeController = Em.Controller.extend(
  actions:
    add_new: ->
      this.store.createRecord('post', {title: 'new post'})
)
```

I don't want an to update the template explicity from the controller.
I'm using Ember *1.1.2* and Ember-Data *1.0.0.beta3*

Comment: is it intentionally that you are not calling `save` on the newly created record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch from findAll to find, and use all as your filter.

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    this.store.find('post') // find has to be called once for the all filter to work
    return this.store.all('post')
)
```

BTW, I'm no coffeescript expert, so that was a guess at syntax.

Comment: it's not necessary to switch to `findAll` because `find` invokes `findAll` under the hood: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L307

Comment: Yes, but it's pointless to use findAll, since find calls findAll

Answer (score 0):

I've figured that out after reading this(http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/)

store.find with query will not update on push.
**store.filter** will.

The article explains it pretty good.

Comment: That's what all will do, why I said it ;)

Comment: all is an active filter that will always return all of the items in the store for a particular class type